# What are non character keys called?

Tags: keyboard, textfield

What would be the proper term for a key on a keyboard that are not a char but have an affect on a text-field?

- backspace
- arrow keys
- delete

etc..

Comment: _non-character keys_..?

Comment: @moffeltje yes, but non-character key would also include the function keys, caps lock and so forth. Would it not?